# ReactJS loading stateful data, optimisations

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm new to ReactJS and using it with Django Rest Framework (DRF)

```
def MyModel(model):
    ...
    status = ChoiceField(['new', 'in progress', 'completed'...])
```

In my app, I have seperate sections for each state. So the data needs to be seperated.
My issue is there are quite a few different states, about 6 or 7.

So I was using different routes for each status. /new, /inprogress etc. But this results in about 7 requests each time instead of just 1.

```
loadMymodelsFromServer: function () {
    this.loadNewMymodelsFromServer();
    this.loadAssignedMymodelsFromServer();
    this.loadAllocatedMymodelsFromServer();
    this.loadDraftMymodelsFromServer();
    this.loadPublishedMymodelsFromServer();
    this.loadArchivedMymodelsFromServer()
    this.loadSponsoredMymodelsFromServer();
    this.loadCurrentUserMymodelsFromServer();
},

loadNewMymodelsFromServer: function() {
    var url = this.props.url + "/new/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: (function (data) {
            this.setState({ new_mymodels: data });
        }).bind(this),
        error: (function (xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(url, status, err.toString());
        }).bind(this)
    });
},
```

The data has to be refreshed a few times, on things like delete operations and update operations, as JS arrays don't support these operations that well.

Would it be better just to load all the data unsorted in one giant request and sort it in a JS for loop?

It feels wrong as I know the database is optimised to query parameters like this, not Javascript, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "JS arrays don't support these operations that well." - it will almost always be _faster_ to splice a JS array and update in place (usually measured in _micro_seconds) than it will be to make a network call to refetch the data (usually measured in 10's or 100's of _milli_seconds).

Comment: This is true, but regardless of that, this system uses polling for live updates

It will eventually use sockets instead, but either way there will still need to be network calls for that too

Comment: Any reason you don't just have one Ajax call that runs all of your queries and returns an object with all of the results so you can just make a single call instead of 7?

Comment: Would I have to make the singular response to be like [{queryset_one_objects},...,{queryset_seven_objects}] 
Or is there a way to make 7 queries to different urls in one ajax call?

Comment: It would be a singular response. Your server side handler could just call the 7 existing queries and collect the results into a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having 7 individual ajax calls, you could just make a single ajax call that returns all 7 results as a single object.

The server handler for the new ajax call can just invoke the other 7 queries and collect the results into a single object.

Here's some pseudo-code for the server:

```
function megaQueryHandler() {
    var result = {
       query1Data: query1Handler(),
       query2Data: query2Handler(),
       ...
    };

    return result;
}
```

Then your client can just make a single call to this "mega query".